# array chain around complex curve

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to array the chain around those curves but i don't know how to it, everytime i do it is completely deformed and doesn't follow the curve ( you can see the images in the links below ) and also the blender file below. Please help, thank you!

Link to images are here
https://ibb.co/Ph4Dyvs
https://ibb.co/4RD8zvH

BLENDER file here
https://file.io/mEwGrABWYgvv

Comment: Apply chain rotation and use Y as axis. But as the curve is made of several parts, I don't think that can do it.

Comment: Please add any images directly into your question instead of posting links to them on external sites. See [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). Also use Blender's built-in screenshot facility via the Window > Save Screenshot menu rather than taking photos of your screen. Your Blend file has already been deleted from that external site. Use https://blend-exchange.com/ where the file will remain available for people viewing your question in future.

Comment: your blend file link doesn't work