How do I make a grease pencil stroke ONLY draw on a mesh's surface?
I know how to use the surface setting in "Stroke Placement" in draw mode but how do I make it ONLY draw on the surface. Whenever I am drawing and I move the cursor off of the mesh, it still draws and snaps and goes from surface, to acting like it's set to stroke. It looks like that is the default, so I want it to stop drawing whenever I move the cursor away like I'm texture painting the mesh.

If you're using the Surface option under Offset Value in the 3d workspace, then it should draw on your mesh. Are you still holding down your mouse when you drag away from the object? If so, that may be part of the problem. Otherwise try adjusting your Offset value to 0.

It's on zero. I am holding down the mouse the whole time I'm drawing. Whenever my cursor leaves the mesh while I'm drawing, it jumps to where I'm viewing from as if that were the surface.

https://screenrec.com/share/mr9BntECDO

Hello, please upload screenshots/gifs, not links, of your issue to your original posts. See comments here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310876/array-chain-around-complex-curve
